# Table structure using sp_help

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I tried this query:

```
sp_help '[OG_System].[dbo].[tbl_act]'
```

This message appears:

> Msg 15250, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_help, Line 48
>       The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.

Comment: You should be in the same database where the table is created. `USE OG_System`

Comment: Try adding `use [OG_System] go` before the `sp_help` statement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your target database is different than current database.

Use;

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_help 'tbl_act'
```

Comment: I think you mean `sp_help` instead of `sp_helptext`.

Comment: EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_help 'tbl_act'

Comment: @ylleigh12 yes, because of phone call I pressed enter :) You can upvote and mark it as solved if it works

Answer (score 0):

thanks goGud, I know the correct usage of sp_columns.

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_columns 'tbl_act'
```