Join 2 databases (both on the same server)
I need to join 2 databases, I am using Delphi and ZeosLib.
The reason: my client has an application which manages their vacations and which is saved in the first database, now I shall write a program which uploads the vacations in an Exchange server. But to know which vacation I already updated I made a second database to compare both. One problem might be that the name of the database is the IP address.
Queries like this work (it does not include the second database yet):
select ur_id as m_id
     , dbo.urlaub.ur_status      as m_status
     , dbo.urlaub.ur_start       as m_start
     , dbo.urlaub.ur_end         as m_end
     , dbo.urlaub.ur_description as m_description
  from dbo.urlaub
 inner join dbo.users
    on dbo.urlaub.ur_user_id = dbo.users.id;

Queries like this do not work (includes the second database) - it works in the database program but not in my program:
select m_urlaub.ur_id          as m_id
     , m_urlaub.ur_status      as m_status
     , m_urlaub.ur_start       as m_start
     , m_urlaub.ur_end         as m_end
     , m_urlaub.ur_description as m_description
     , ex_urlaub.ur_status     as ex_status
  from kalender.dbo.urlaub     as m_urlaub
 inner join kalender.dbo.users                as m_users
    on m_urlaub.ur_user_id  = m_users.id
  full outer join exchangerelation.dbo.urlaub as ex_urlaub
    on ex_urlaub.ur_id      = m_urlaub.ur_id;

(This is only an example what does work and what not, it's not my real query - only one which I used to test if everything works.) I get to work with MSSQL as database for this project. I always get the "EZSQLException":

[15250] The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.

The database has already a lot of data saved, so it would not be nice if my program needs to sort every data. Both databases use the same host, port, username and password - the only difference is their name:

db #1 = kalender
db #2 = exchangerelation

Do I need to use TZGroupedConnection or TZConnectionGroup? I tried to change the database name in the TZConnection to the IP of the database (which should also be their name), kalender, exchangerelation, master (also everything with  / and \\).
Sadly I haven't found a good explanation about both TZ..., or how to join multiple databases with ZeosLib.

SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

mssql thanks and sorry for that information

As an FYI then,  3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the FROM and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Sounds like your orm (and i use the term loosely) doesn't support a lot. Could you create a view that does the "JOIN" and just select against it?

Alternatively, you could create SYNONYMs in the database you connect to that point to the objects in the other database.

The question isn't entirely clear, is the database engine in question MS SQL Server?

@siggemannen that actually is my solution right now and it works fine but I still don't know what caused the error.

If i google the error it leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466815/table-structure-using-sp-help so i'm guessing the ZEOS is using that procedure to look up stuff under the covers.
